# Allow users to buy additions to my app via google - Android

Tags: android

I have looked around on the internet and cannot find anything on this topic. If my app is a game and I want users to buy tokens from me for a price and they pay one dollar for 100 tokens, how can I make my app communicate with google and bring up a menu so they can purchase through google? Is there any tutorials on this subject?

To make sure people understand it, If my app has an Activity which has a button that reads "100 tokens for 1$" Then another button that reads "500 tokens for 2$" and they click either button, it will bring up a google popup that says purchase. Then it uses their google account information through the app market to purchase the tokens. Many apps have this feature so I hope you know what I am talking about.

Please help me out, and thanks.

Also, I have looked at In-App Billing and they say you must post your app on the Google Play market complete the In-App Billing process. How can I add my app to Google Play without users being able to download or even see it. I want to upload for only developing reasons

Comment: You're looking for In-app billing: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html

Comment: Thanks! I added more to my question, please take a look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In-App Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html) is indeed the correct approach for having user purchases within your application. As you mentioned, this is only available via Google Play published apps. However, if you do not want to publish your app publically, you can use Google Play's [Beta-testing program](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) to upload an app to Google Play but only make it available to a specific group of people (those who you allow to join a Google Group or Google+ Community).

As long as you never publish a production version and only publish to the alpha/beta channel in the Google Play Developer Console, then you can create an app that utilizes In-App Billing without being public.